# Is there an Erde/Himmel relationship between Erdbeeren and Himbeeren?

Tags: etymology

It struck me last night that the "Him" of Himbeere could in some sense be in opposition to the apparent "Erde" of Erdbeere. Is there an etymological connection here?

Since these are not, e.g., Himmelbeeren, I'm assuming any connection would have originated long before modern German.

Comment: [Nope.](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Himbeere) [Yup.](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Erdbeere)

Comment: See [Kluge](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/An_Etymological_Dictionary_of_the_German_Language/Annotated/Himbeere) and [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Himbeere), the "Him" is cognate to English "hind" (doe). The 'n' changed to 'm' because of a standard sound change in German (as well as English). There are many animal and plant names in German with interesting derivations, but I don't think this is one of them.

Comment: I closed this question, because it can be solved by looking the two terms up in a dictionary, for instance at dwds.de

Comment: If someone asks a question in English, then one cannot assume that a completely German site like DWDS will help them. Especially if it is linked without further explanation.

Comment: I think the closure means a "very likely, no".

Comment: It‘s a frequently encountered folk etymology, though. And those are often more useful explanations than OHG or even PIE origins.

Answer (score 4):

While the "Erdbeere" really is the fruit from the soil (*Erde*), the raspberry (*Himbeere*) is the *hindberry*, the berry of the *hind*, which is a nordic name for the deer.